# Windows phone, Android OS

Tags: applications, windows, operating-system

I made the mistake of getting a windows phone because the price was enticing. I want to run android O.S. if at all possible, being a working full time school full time person I'm looking to save money. Really I need the applications so I can interact with the rest of the world.

Answer (score 0):

NO you can't based on the hardware and most windows phone are made by nokia which android doesn't support, if its been less then 2 weeks most phone providers will allow you to exchange your phone.